# Why is `sz +“text”` different from `sz + “text”` in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

In coffeescript `sz +"text"` is different from `sz + "text"`. Note the space after `+`. Why is that? I can't find mention of it on [the coffeescript website](http://coffeescript.org/). What's a good use for that syntax? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coffescript has significant whitespaces. And you don't need to use parentheses to invoke a function if you're passing arguments. `a b c` means `a(b(c))`. Not sure if it is good or bad. But this is actually common practice in functional programming languages where "the most important construction" is function call.

The first expression `sz +"text"` was parsed to

```
    call
sz       UnaryPlus
                  "text"
```

The second `sz + "text"` was parsed to

```
    +
sz    "text"
```

BTW do not use `+` to concat strings. Coffescript supports string interpolation.

```
sz = 'hello' # single quotes no interpolation
"#{sz}text" # double quotes compiles to `sz + "text";`
```

Comment: 1) I think you got it swapped. The first one (`sz +"text")` treats sz as a function call. 2) What is a good use for this? It's weird something outside of sz controlls whether or not sz is a function call 3) I forgot coffeescript does that. But the problem still happens if you write something like `(25+3) +"text"` which is one of the few times you can't use interpolation

Comment: 1) True. :) 2) Well, its kinda opinion based. For some reason ML FP camp tends to avoid () by all means. IMHO it definitely makes code harder to read if overused 3) You can use expressions inside template strings `"#{25 + 3} apples"`